# Hash collision worries

Tags: php, algorithm, hash, probability, hash-collision

If I have a system where a hash is generated out of a total permutation of 1 million possibilities. If there's a 10% chance of a collision, should I worry about the generating algorithm running 5 times?

- I have a system similar to jsfiddle, where a user can "save" a file on my server. Now I'm using `'23456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'` which is 33 chars, and the file is 4 chars long, for a total of `33^4 = 1,185,921` possibilities.
- The "filename" is generated randomly and if there's a collision it reruns to get another filename. Using a [birthday paradox calculator](http://jeff.aaron.ca/cgi-bin/birthday) I can see that after I have 500 entries I have a 10% chance of a collision.
- What are the chances that I'll get a collision more than 5 times in a row? what about 4?
- Is there any way to figure this out? Should I worry about it? What happens after 5000 entries?
- Is there a program out there that can figure this out with any arbitary inputs?

Comment: It seems to me that your keyspace is too small, why only 4 characters?  For short URLs?

Comment: Hm - can't you use the birthday paradox, replacing 365 with the number of possible hashes to get to your result? I guess that'd give you the odds - and for 5000 hashes the odds are ones you'd bet money on.

Comment: @ExternalUse I think that's what OP did. If you replace 365 with 1185921 and try to generate 500 values, odds are just under 10% that two will be the same.

Comment: Oh - I've misread the question. He wanted to know about the probability of it happening in a row. For that my answer is: The odds for that are identical.

Comment: @ExternalUse the chance of a coin to land on one side is 1/2 but the probability for it to land on one side twice is (1/2)^2 = 1/4

Comment: @noHDD - That's wrong. The chance of landing on _a specific_ side twice = 1/4. The chance of landing on (heads twice or tails twice) is 1/2.

Comment: @noHDD Isn't it `1 / (o ^ n)` where `o` is the number of possible outcomes and `n` is the number of sequential events?

Comment: I can't help thinking this question would find a better home and better answers over at http://math.stackexchange.com/...

Comment: @DaveRandom I will cite my math book from swedish; "According to the classical possibility definition P(Tails and Heads) = 1/4 because we only have one positive possibility within our four possible outcomes. This is the same as P(Tails) * P(Heads) = 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4 = (1/2) ^ 2 = 2 ^ -2" Your solution is correct too: 1 / (o ^ n) = (1 / o) ^ n. I also agree that its better suited at Math :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the birthday paradox calculations apply. There's a difference between the odds of 500 random numbers out of 1185921 being all different and the odds of one new number being different once you have 500 known unique numbers.

If you have 500 assigned numbers and generate a new number at random, it will have odds of 500/1185921 of being a collision. With 500 names taken, the chances of 4 collisions in a row are (500/1185921)<sup>4</sup> < 10<sup>-13</sup>. With 5000 existing file names, the odds of a new name being a collision are 5000/1185921, and the chance of 4 collisions in a row are < 10<sup>-9</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

My math is a little rusty so bear with me.
The chance of getting x collisions in a row is simply:

```
chance of collision ^ x;
```

Where the chance of collision is:

```
entries/space (which is 500/1185921 or 0.04%).
```

You can see above that this will get worse with the more entries (and better with a bigger space).

Also note the birthday paradox is perhaps not quite what you want. The 10% chance is the chance that any two entries will have had a collision, not the chance of a collision for the next entry.